# My php or Mysqli time / timestamps seem out?

Tags: php, timestamp

The code is

```
$la=time()-$row['laston'];
$unit="secs";
if($la >= 60)
{
$la=(int) ($la/60);
$unit="mins";
}
if($la >= 60)
{
$la=(int) ($la/60);
$unit="hours";
if($la >= 24)
{
$la=(int) ($la/24);
$unit="days";
}
print "<li><a class=\"button\" href=\"user.php?p={$row['uid']]'}\">{$row['display_name']} ~($la $unit)</a></li>";
```

and `$row['laston'];` is stored like: `1392490566`

My problem is it is showing like:

User1  ~(-58secs) when i refresh the page, I'd expect it to be 0-2 secs not a negative value?

Could someone please help me understand what is causing this?

and would changing `$la=time()-$row['laston'];` to `$la=time()-$row['laston']+58;` be an appropriate fix?

Comment: What does `var_dump($row['laston']);` output?

Comment: @AmalMurali `User1     ~(-57 secs)
string(10) "1392491868" ` (I added it to the line right after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$la = time() - $row['laston'];

if($la > 0) {
    $newLa = $la / 24;
    $unit = "days";
} if($la < 84600) {
    $newLa = $la / 60;
    $unit = "hours";
} if($la < 3600) {
    $newLa = $la / 60;
    $unit = "mins";
} if($la < 60) {
    $newLa = $la;
    $unit = "secs";
} 

echo round($newLa, 2) . ' ' . $unit;
```